# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type vistula.ym.myonlinetest.UserModel

Tags: android, firebase

```
public class ListTasks extends AppCompatActivity{
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<UserModel> result;
    private UserAdapter adapter;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_tasks);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = database.getReference("users");
        result = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.user_list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        emptyText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_no_data);
        adapter = new UserAdapter(result);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        updateList();   
    }
    private void updateList(){
        reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                result.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                checkEmpty();
            }
        });
    }
```

I am facing the following error com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type

I have a problem with  result.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class));

Help me solve this error.

There is a UserModel class

```
public class UserModel {
    String firstName, lastName, job, key;
    int age;

    public UserModel(){}

    public UserModel(String firstName, String lastName, String job, int age, String key) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.job = job;
        this.age = age;
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> toMap(){
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        result.put("firstName", firstName);
        result.put("lastName", lastName);
        result.put("job", job);
        result.put("age", age);
        result.put("key", key);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: add the database

Comment: But why I have the exeption?

Comment: because you may be getting the value of a string or you are referencing in a wrong place..

Comment: Please add you database structure. The reason is that you have added the listener in an incorrect place.